# Page content won't center

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm almost embarrassed to ask help with this. It's not like I've never done this before - with the exact code I'm using now!

For the life of me, I can't understand why the content of a new page won't center in the browser window.

The HTML I have is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Home</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainContainer">
            Main Content Goes Here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
body { background-color: #EDEDC7; }

#mainContainer {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
```

What's happening is the text is being positioned about 1/3 of the way from the left edge of whatever browser window I view the page in. I know the stylesheet is "being found" by the web page because the background color is working.

I've checked it in FF8, IE9, Chrome, Safari 5, the latest versions of Opera and Dragon - even FF, Safari and Chrome on Mac! Okay - a little obsessive, I know, but I'm stumped as to why it won't center. So what the heck am I missing here? (Probably some stupid little thing I'm forgetting, too...)

Comment: It is working properly in Firefox. Do you want to center text also?

Comment: Nothing. That works as expected.

Comment: Oh crap - I'm kicking myself - Pradeep's question about centering the text did it. My div **is** being centered - I just don't have enough content in the div to see that it is centered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, the problem is that your text is not centered. If you add text align center to it it will work the way you are expecting.

example:

```
#mainContainter{
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center text inside that container you need to put it in a separate div, format the width of that div(where your text need to go) and center it..

In your example it is centering the div which has length 1000px so there is no problem in code..:)

Answer (score -1):

if that did work you could always use:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```